# If a multi row account has a row in a specified date range, how to select all previous rows for that account before that date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table that looks like the following:

| Account | Sale | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | $5 | 2023-Jan-01 |
| A | $8 | 2023-Feb-15 |
| B | $2 | 2023-Mar-03 |
| A | $7 | 2023-Apr-10 |
| A | $9 | 2024-Jan-01 |

If a user selects a date range of 2023-Apr-01 to 2023-Apr-30 I would want the table to filter down to the below:

| Account | Sale | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | $5 | 2023-Jan-01 |
| A | $8 | 2023-Feb-15 |
| A | $7 | 2023-Apr-10 |

Where I can not only see the account within that specified date range, but also all previous sales on that account before the specified date range. Simply doing `SELECT * WHERE Date < 2023-Apr-30` would return:

| Account | Sale | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | $5 | 2023-Jan-01 |
| A | $8 | 2023-Feb-15 |
| B | $2 | 2023-Mar-03 |
| A | $7 | 2023-Apr-10 |

Which is not the desired result. I initially did a partition like `MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Date) AS Max_Date`:

| Account | Sale | Date | Max_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | $5 | 2023-Jan-01 | 2024-Jan-01 |
| A | $8 | 2023-Feb-15 | 2024-Jan-01 |
| B | $2 | 2023-Mar-03 | 2023-Mar-03 |
| A | $7 | 2023-Apr-10 | 2024-Jan-01 |
| A | $9 | 2024-Jan-01 | 2024-Jan-01 |

and did `SELECT * WHERE Max_Date < 2023-Apr-30` which would work if the max sale date for A was 2023-Apr-30 but because it is 2024-Jan-01 the result would be an empty table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want an `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT YT.Account,
       YT.Sale,
       YT.Date
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.YourTable E
              WHERE E.Account = YT.Account
                AND E.Date >= @StartDate
                AND E.Date <= @EndDate); --If date is actually a date and time value you will want:
                                         --E.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
```